# Can't set cookie in NSURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cookies, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

In my program I call two functions, the first a a login, the second one a function to parse data.

To store session, with the login function I save my cookies with this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
    if(connection == conn_login){
        NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        NSDictionary *fields = [HTTPResponse allHeaderFields];
        cookie = [fields valueForKey:@"Set-Cookie"];
    }
}
```

Everything is fine, when I print cookie it is:

```
userid=1; expires=Mon, 05-Aug-2013 19:22:18 GMT; path=/; domain=www.mydomain.com
```

"userid=1" is what I'm interested in.

So in the following NSURLRequest where I parse the data, I do like this to set the saved cookie:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
URLWithString:@"http://www.mydomain.com/?getList"]];
[request setValue:cookie forHTTPHeaderField:@"Set-Cookie"];
```

But it doesn't work. My previous cookies are not set, and even if a print the complete header of the 2nd request, there is no "userid" or whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use this line of code... If you have doubts let me know

```
NSArray *cookies1 = [[ NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies ];

NSDictionary *cookieHeaders;

cookieHeaders = [ NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies: cookies1];

[request setValue: [cookieHeaders objectForKey: @"Cookie" ]forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie" ];
```